# Experiment with spring and two light sources emitting light in opposite directions

Tags: speed-of-light, spring

Two (almost massless) light sources connected with a (almost massless) spring emit light beams in opposite directions. What is the speed at which the spring extends?

Comment: Can you expand on what you are asking. The force on the light source due to the emission of the light is easily calculated, and the acceleration of the light source is just this force less the spring tension divided by the light source mass.

Comment: I want to learn the speed at which such a spring would extend. The answer from Rohan Vijjhalwar indicates it would be approx. the speed of light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring would extend at a below light speed (but very close to it) this is because of it having some mass as you referred the spring to being "nearly mass-less" but it would extend on each side, therefore no physical law is broken however relative to an observer it would seem as if the object is expanding at faster than $c$ (Speed of Light) speed however in a different frame of reference in such that we are travelling with the particle it'd seem as if its expanding very quickly but not as fast as $c$.

That in mind, it would expand at near light speed however it will never reach it  relative to observer but if you look at whole picture it will seem as if it was expanding at that rate so Einstein still has the last-laugh as the difference is actually what you are looking at and since no information can be passed via the difference it can never travel faster than light. That being said, NOTHING that carries usable information can travel at light-speed or above it.

To elaborate further, even if the spring was mass-less it will never go faster than light but rather at speed of light as you must look at a individual point that is moving rather than the difference between the 2 points as they are moving in different directions but if they were expanding in the same direction, I can assure you they will never go faster than speed of light.